# Iterate over a string in Python and add some new characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to iterate over a string in Python and add some whitespace characters after existing ones in certain cases. So I need smth like the following code (ofc, it doesn't work):

```
for i, c in enumerate(some_string):
  if c == ' ':
    rand_value = random.randint(0, 2)
    if rand_value == 0:
      # Place two whitespaces here
    elif rand_value == 1:
      # Place three whitespaces here
```

Also I know that I can't modify string object while iterating over it.

How can I write such code in Python?

Example:

Input -- `"some string with whitespace characters"`
Possible outputs -- `"some  string with   whitespace characters"`, `"some string  with whitespace characters"`, `"some   string with whitespace   characters"`, etc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert to list with `some_string = list(some_string)` - modify - `''.join(some_string)`?

Comment: please place some input and expected output so that it is easy to solve

Comment: So, if the string is a space... then leave it as one space, make it two spaces or three spaces at random ?

Comment: @Jon Clements I've added an example

Comment: @FrozenHeart it not clear man! . please be clear

Comment: @Sundar Nataraj Oh, that's formatting. Sorry, wait a sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go for:

```
import re
from random import randint

text = 'this is some example text'
for i in xrange(5):
    print re.sub(' ', lambda m: m.group() * randint(1, 3), text)
```

Which gives:

```
this   is   some  example text
this is some  example   text
this  is some example  text
this is   some example   text
this is   some example text
```

This reads as, find a space, then replace it by 1 to 3 spaces... it should be straight forward enough to adapt to other scenarios more easily than looping/re-joining etc...

Answer (score 3):

A concise solution:

```
from random import choice
output = ''.join([choice(['  ', '   ']) if c==' ' else c for c in input])
```

For each character in the input string, if the current character is a space, output either two or three spaces selected randomly; for any input other than space, copy to output.  Then since the result of the `[list comprehension]` is a list, join the characters to make a new string.